# Spring MVC Junit tests are not being executed

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to build tests for my MVC controllers. I followed the example on the  [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server) and when doing mvn test the tests are not being executed.

Any idea what I am missing?

One weird log is that maven says is trying to `Configuring TestNG`while I not useing TestNg at all.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNGMapConfigurator@4f4a7090
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.362 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

The tests are under the test folder in my project, 
I am using `Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE`.

**Junit Code:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com"})
public class TestSignUpController {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAccount() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/validateEmail").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"));
    }
}
```

**Maven says:**

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

**Effective pom**

```
<parent>
    ...
  </parent>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>paypal-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1-b02</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
      <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>

    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\target</directory>
    <finalName>aFileName</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>../deploy</outputDirectory>
              <warName>app</warName>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>../deploy</outputDirectory>
          <warName>app</warName>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: can you do a "mvn help:effective-pom" and look at the surefire plugin? It should be ok but it may be reconfigured in the project, the default includes seem to match: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes - maybe the junit version is too old and does not scan for annotations?

Comment: I think `@ComponentScan` only works with classes annotated with`@Configuration`. cf http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Comment: @wemu I added the effective pom. I am using Junit 4.1 which should be Ok.

Comment: @DonBottstein so how can I scan my project for the autowire?

Comment: I find the easiest option is to create a nested static class that is annotated with `@Configure` and `@ComponentScan`. e.g., `@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com"})
public static class TestConfig {}` within your test class. You can also use an external class, but then you need to tell Spring the name of the class, e.g. with `@ContextConfiguration( classes = TestConfig.class )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUnit Test case classes should always end on `Test` - refactore your `TestSignUpController` class  to `TestSignUpControllerTest` and your test should run in the maven `test` phase. See http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/03/17/getting-junit-test-names-right/ and [Naming convention JUnit suffix or prefix Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146821/naming-convention-junit-suffix-or-prefix-test)